# How to find the variance between two groups in python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this,

```
ID   total_sec   is_weekday
1      300           1
1      200           0
2      280           1
2      260           0
3      190           1
4      290           0
5      500           1
5      520           0
```

I want to find the ID with the largest variance between weekdays and weekends. If we missed the records for either weekdays or weekends, we calculate the variance as 0.
My expected output will be,

```
ID   variance
1       100
2       20
3       0
4       0
5       20
```

Comment: So you want the highest difference? Is it always only two? So weekday and weekend? And you want the difference between weekdays and weekends?

Comment: does ID always have 2 rows ? if not can you post a better example :) Thanks

Comment: @LeoE Some of the IDs only have one of them. So I want to calculate the difference as `0`.

Comment: Hi @anky_91 No, some of the IDs only have one of them. So I mentioned the difference as `0` in ID ='3' and ID='4'.

Comment: i think the answer below with an `.abs()` at the end should answer your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```py
df.pivot(index="ID", columns="is_weekday", values="total_sec").diff(axis=1)[1].fillna(0)
```

Outputs:

```py
ID
1    100.0
2     20.0
3      0.0
4      0.0
5    -20.0
Name: 1, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

So long as you can guarantee you have 1-2 rows per ID and each row has a different `'is_weekday'` value then you really just want the "peak-to-peak" (`ptp`) value. If not, figure out how to resolve duplicates on `['ID', 'is_weekday']` then use `ptp`.

```
import numpy as np

df.groupby('ID').total_sec.agg(np.ptp)
```

---

```
ID
1    100
2     20
3      0
4      0
5     20
Name: total_sec, dtype: int64
```